# No video output on HDMI to VGA with shutdown commands

Tags: raspbian, boot, shutdown

My Raspberry Pi has following issue:
It doesnt make any video output after booting if shut down by command

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

or by taking the plug out. However, if I send via SSH or by blindly typing with keyboard

```
sudo reboot
```

the issue seems to be gone after restarting the device. Is this a known issue? What might be the cause?

Comment: `shutdown` is managed by **systemd**. Try to use systemd direct with `sudo systemctl poweroff`.

Comment: @Ingo nope, this one didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other people looking for this issue - solution in my case was hidden in video configuration file. When using the HDMI to VGA converter boot configuration file (`/boot/config.txt`) must contain proper entry of `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` in order to work with every startup.